# PHP: get SESSION variable from string

Tags: php, session-variables

I have this $res variable that gets a result from a DB query. The result contains the name of a session variable in a string. That session variable is already set and has the value of 5 (INTIGER), for example:

```
$res = mysql_query('SELECT `result` from `table`....');
....
gives the $res variable this string value: "Result: $_SESSION[myVar]";
print_r($res); // outputs Result: $_SESSION[myVar] and not "Result: 5"
```

How can I parse the string to get the value of the session variable?

Comment: You need to use concatenation or simply wrap the $_SESSION[$yourVar'] with {}

Comment: @RohitS can you give me an example, please? I query a database and the string that I get contains the name of the variable. It already has a value, I just need to transform that name into the value:  $_SESSION[myVar]  into 5, or whatever that value is. Tks!

Comment: Sure.. lets say you query database and get "Index" in some value like $res. Now the $res is like `$res = "index"` Now simply to use it for echoing content from session value like `$_SESSION[$res]`. As the string "index" in your case it might be "5" is retrieved in variable you have to use it.

Comment: if you are looking out for string concatenation you have to use `.`  (Period) operator and when you directly quote your PHP variable into string you need to simply wrap them in {}

Comment: @RohitS, tks much! That is a solution to get just the name in the $_SESSION. But I have different situations, where the variable could be $_GET or $_POST. That's why I get the whole "$_SESSION[....]" and parse it into its value. The whole case is quite complex, even if it might look stupid to get reference to those types of vars from database.

Comment: ok. looks like i didn't got the root of and looks like you were looking out for getting some PHP variable from database and then use it..anyways you have your solution... cheers!

Comment: @RohitS, tks much! I finally ended up with this solution: `preg_match("/$_(.*?)\[(.*?)\](?:\[(.*?)\])?/",$VAR,$matches);`where i get an array and retrieve the case of variable ($_SESSION, $_POST, $_SERVER etc.) and its corresponding key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start a session and echo the variable.

```
<?php
session_start();
$myvar=$_SESSION["myVar"];
echo "Result: ".$myvar;
?>
```

Edit: What you can do is:

```
preg_match_all("/\[([^\]]*)\]/",$res,$matches);
$var=matches[1];
$session=$_SESSION[$var];
echo $session;
```

This finds the var used in the string for the session. Then it inputs it into the $_SESSION to get that session variable.

Comment: The value of $res comes from a database query and it is a string. I need to parse it without using EVAL(), which works fine and parse the $_SESSION[myVar] to its existing value.

Comment: I added a fix to your problem above.

Comment: Thanks much, that is a good solution!

Comment: @AlinB. Perfect, can you accept the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Based on your suggestion, I ended up using this: `preg_match("/$_(.*?)\[(.*?)\]/",$k,$matches);` and I take both the type of variable (SESSION, POST, GET) and its name between the parenthesis.

Comment: I accepted the answer. Sorry, I am quite new here, I only now understood what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

Use string concatenation:

```
$res = "Result: ".$_SESSION[myVar];
print_r($res);
```

Comment: what is myvar? either it should be wrapped in quotes or need to be literal!

Comment: The $res gets that string from a database query. And it gets it as such. It works if I EVAL() that string, but I want to avoid using that solution.

Comment: I'd suggest you to use: mysql_fetch_assoc and get help from documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: @Abhishek thanks for the tip but I already get the $res using fetch_assoc. Is there another way to get the value of the $_SESSION[...] variable contained into that result other than using EVAL()?

Answer (score 0):

should read `$res = "Result:" . $_SESSION[myVar];`